# Routing issue if I place a form first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed the rails tutorial by michale hartl, I then wanted to extend it, so I attempted to integrate the thumbs_up gem. I was able to get voting working for both posts and comments, and was very proud. But then I wanted to work on my UI a little. I didn't like that all the forms for adding a new comment was below the feed of comments attached to the post. So I thought that all i had to do was change the order of my partials

from this

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: my_item.comments, as: :comment %>
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :cur_post => my_item } %>
```

to this

```
<%= render :partial => "comments/form", :locals => { :cur_post => my_item } %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', collection: my_item.comments, as: :comment %>
```

and it would work. But this was sadly not the case. When I reorder them I get this error.

```
No route matches {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"comments", :id=>#<Comment id: nil, content: nil, user_id: nil, post_id: 14, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}
```

I am able to remove either partial and everything will work, so I am unsure why having the form above the comments causes an error.

Here is a link to a [gist](https://gist.github.com/a5f658a2b4f1854ef2f0)

any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from this line I believe

```
<%= form_for([cur_post, cur_post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

When this occurs first, it builds a new Comment onto cur_post.comments. The problem occurs now, when you render "comments/comment" that newly built comment isn't saved. Rails expects when you pass a model into a url helper like this:

```
vote_up_comment_path(comment)
```

That the object is in the db (AFAIK)

You should be able to get around this by not building into the `comments` assocaition

```
<%= form_for([cur_post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>
```

otherwise, in your comments/comment you could check to see if `comment.new_record?` is true and deal with it accordingly.

Comment: Awesome, both of those solutions work. I figured it was something to do with the potentiality of the comment in the form. But I didn't know how to protect against it. Of these 2 solutions which is the more correct ?

Comment: Either one. The first one. Where you use `Comment.new` in the form.